# How to create a query string filtering the search by specific parameters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

Usually, when I have to make a GET request using NodeJS and MongoDB, I do a separate search for every field.

**For Example:**

```
localhost:3000/movie/:name/:author - GET
```

As I would expect to get a movie, desired name, and author, everything will be working fine.

But what if I want to make a request query like this:

```
localhost:3000/movies/filters[‘movies’]=USA&fields=id,name,author - GET
```

Is that possible in NodeJS and MongoDB using the SAME query?

How can it be done?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In the first route you're using [**request parameters**](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params). In the second route you're trying to use [**request queries**](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) on the route: `/movies`. (Query strings are not part of the route path)

But you're slightly off, in express, you can do a GET request with string queries like this:

```
localhost:3000/movies?filters[movies]=USA&fields[]=id&fields[]=name
                     ^               ^   ^      ^
                     1               2   3      4
```

1. `?`  Indicates start of query string
2. `=`  Separates key from its value
3. `&`  Separates each key=value pair
4. `[]` To treat key as an array

Then you can access the values in the router by using the [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) property:

```
router.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.filters.movies); // => USA
    console.log(req.query.fields);         // => [ 'id', 'name' ]
});
```

To learn more, I suggest you read the official [Express routing guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).